# Why are my mouse events not being triggered?

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is an example of one of my forms mouse event handlers:

```
private void GENIO_Viewer_Form_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        m_bLeftButton = true;
        m_MousePosition = e.Location;
        m_MouseClick = e.Location;

        if(m_bZoomWindow)
        {
            m_Points.Clear();
            m_Points.Add(GetWorldCoordinates(e.Location));
        }
    }

    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}
```

I have placed a breakpoint in it and it never gets triggered. Have I missed something in my form definition or something?

Update:

The form has an enlarged **TableLayerPanel** so I have added a additional event handler:

```
private void tableLayoutPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Yes");
}
```

But even this does not get intercepted. The tableLayoutPanel in turn is displaying a UserControl1 object (derived from UserControl).

Problem is, even if I add the right handler (to UserControl) I still have to feed that back up to the form itself as that is where my processing needs to be done.

Update: This is a partial list of the event handlers for my form:

[image]

Comment: The form won't get mouse events if there is a control in the way. In other words, the thing that actually gets clicked on receives the mouse events. If that's a control, then the control will get the mouse events. Which is where you should handle them.

Comment: Answers shouldn't be placed in the question.  If you solved your issue, you can post a self-answer below.

Comment: @LarsTech I will (eventually) but I am trying out this PreviewMouseDown.

Comment: And what happened?

Comment: @FirstStep Struggled with it as you will see. Just added my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't seem to get the PreviewMouseDown event to work. I tried manually editing the code and it would not compile.

Based on someone's comment, I established the fact that I had to intercept the message with the right control, the one with focus. This was an object derived from **UserControl**.

So I had to add my event handlers to *that* class. Eg:

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        m_bLeftButton = true;
        m_MousePosition = e.Location;
        m_MouseClick = e.Location;

        if (m_bZoomWindow)
        {
            m_Points.Clear();
            m_Points.Add(GetWorldCoordinates(e.Location));
        }
    }

    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}
```

Comment: @FirstStep I could not find it. I tried manually typing it in. Got squiggles. Only one that worked was PreviewKeyDown.

Comment: What else do you have above and beyond `PreviewKeyDown`? Could you print screen your event handlers page? Like I did. I am curious now

Comment: PreviewMouseDown doesn't work because it's only in WPF, not WinForms. You've got the right solution here. Guess it figures, I'm the person who left the original comment. :-) You could forward/bubble the event notification up to the parent, if you absolutely wanted to centralize handling, but the spirit of OOP is to keep the code as close to the related object as possible. Single responsibility principle and all that. Another option that is useful in certain cases is to make the control unfocusable so that it never receives mouse events. Like Label controls. Doesn't make sense for Buttons, etc.